# Web page is not resizing on mobile browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, resize

My website is builded with bootstrap v2 and i can't find a solution to the page resize on mobile device ! i used the representative bootstrap css but i got more problems !!
i used this meta to resize the page but the container still not resizing

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Link : http://www.st3s-security.com/fr

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the webpage you provided isn't loading at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these meta tags in your `head` tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mobile%2FViewport_meta_tag